# How to fetch query from multiple tables in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the database I am working on, there are 14 news tables (table1, table2 .... table14) of different cities with exact same structure. Some of the columns are:
id, author, date, news_title, news_body

There are different authors who post in relevant city table. Now I want to know how many news has been posted by each author today in all 14 tables.

Here is the format of output:

```
author | num_of_post
bob          5
peter        12
```

Remember, there are 14 tables (this is the problem)

Comment: You can use `union all`, but at least you've learned something about bad database design.

Comment: use JOINS. This schema is very badly designed btw. https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Does MySQL have Views? or an equivalent? If so, create a view that includes all 14 tables, (use `Union`, or `full join`s). and drive your query against the View.  But why is this data spread across 14 tables instead of being in just one with a column named `city`? Not that that is intrinsically wrong, but there are only a few good reasons to do that.

Comment: @CharlesBretana I have not designed the database

Comment: @Prateek, Didn't accuse you of that.  Was asking why it is the way it is, because it might be for a good reason, but if not, then next question (no matter who built it that way) is can you change it? Sounds like answer is no, or you don't care.

Comment: @CharlesBretana I can not change it now because it is huge database. I am not allowed to do that.

Comment: How big it is does not affect this. If you do not have the authority, and are unable or unwilling to approach the individual who does, well, then, my sympathies.

Comment: As suggested you can use `UNION ALL` and create a view as in `create view all_tables as (select * from table1 union all select * from table2 union all select * from table3 ...)`. Then the long execution time will be the only thing that reminds you of this bad database design when querying the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Grodon already stated you can use union like this:

```
select author, count(id) as num_of_post from table1 group by author
union
select author, count(id) as num_of_post from table2 group by author
union
select author, count(id) as num_of_post from table3 group by author
```

And so on

---

Update:

Because you have records from 1 author in multiple tables, you can group the union result again.

```
select author, sum(num_of_post) from (
 select author, count(id) as num_of_post from table1 group by author
 union
 select author, count(id) as num_of_post from table2 group by author
 union
 select author, count(id) as num_of_post from table3 group by author) a group by author
```

Comment: but it gives 2 or more rows of same author, like this:

author | num_of_post
bob          5
bob          2
peter        3

Comment: if you could add some dummy data I could write the exact query, but according to your comment I now understand that 1 author can have records in multiple tables

Comment: Yes all authors can post in all the tables, therefore it is giving result of same author multiple times. I want to know the total num of post by all authors in all tables. Suppose author1 has posted 1 post in table1, 5 post in table2 and 0 post in all other tables then total num of post by author1 is 6

Comment: could you either try the updated version or could you add some dummy data so I can write the exact query?

Comment: I think it is working, but let me check. Will reply you later

Comment: Gordon's suggestion to use `UNION ALL` is good. This answer, however is not. `UNION` works different from `UNION ALL` in additionally removing duplicates. So if you find 2 records for bob in table 1 and two in table 2 and three in table 3, your result is bob|2, bob|3, and not bob|2, bob|2, bob|3. Hence the sum can be wrong. Use `UNION ALL`instead as suggested by Gordon Linoff.